# The "rel" attribute

Tags: html, rel

I have noticed that the "rel" attribute is not used at all by browsers, does this make it an ideal place to store additional information for javascript (eg a delete ajax request could read the id from rel)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

> I have noticed that the "rel" attribute is not used at all by browsers

You noticed wrong. Browsers do make use of it (e.g. some browsers have a keyboard shortcut to go to the next page and can use the rel attribute to determine that that is). Search engines also make use of it (e.g. nofollow).

> does this make it an ideal place to store additional information for javascript

No. Attributes have specified purposes. Don't assume that they aren't going to be used for that.

Comment: http://www.w3schools.com/TAGS/att_a_rel.asp "Browsers do not use this attribute in any way."

Comment: Also, it seems pretty dangerous to assume that *no* browser will come around that does make good use of a currently large-unused-by-interactive-UAs attribute...

Comment: rel=next in firefox it fetches the link. It's called prefetch.

Comment: if ive got a bunch of different domains with the same root directory (i.e. `public_html`), thus theyre all displaying the same page, and i create a link out of my logo that points to the "parent" page (i.e. `<a href='https://parent.com'>`), what can i use instead of `rel='index'` and `rel='external' since the former is obsolete and the latter isnt always true?

Answer (score 13):

I'm assuming you are looking for a way to store custom data you can use in javascript. I that case:

Storing custom data can be done using `data-` attributes (see [here](http://ejohn.org/blog/html-5-data-attributes/)).

```
<a href="somelink.html" data-id="5">Link 5</a>
```

Alternatively/additionally you could use [jQuery Metadata](http://plugins.jquery.com/project/metadata)

Comment: Worth noting that this is only valid in HTML 5 , it is however the best choice for attaching data to any element , in my opinion

Comment: Using `data-` is 'safe' to use before HTML 5 isn't it?

Comment: Yes, you won't have compatibility issues, however it will cause your pages to not validate under the w3 validation service (if you're not using the html5 doctype that is).

Comment: Some good information available here: https://www.sitepoint.com/use-html5-data-attributes/

Answer (score 1):

The problem you'll have is that search engines **do** make use of the `rel` attribute. While SEO is not my focus, we often have SEO firms telling us to stick a rel in here and a rel in there... usually `rel="nofollow"` to prevent giving weight to certain external links.

Answer (score -1):

You could just create your own custom attributes but make sure that you name it currently as to not conflict with other js libraries that you may use.